# How to save file(.pdf or .txt) in specified location using java dynamic web application

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets

In my java I am using html.

When I click on **save file** button means it should ask, where to save file in specified location.

Please help for this.

```
<form action="downloadPDF.do">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="save file"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: is  it download process or upload process?

Comment: Not upload. Download process. For download process I used some servlet code but its not asking me where save.

Comment: browser automatically asks for it.

Comment: It is automatically save to default location. If I change the settings like ask every time where to download anta. Its working properly. Client should change this settings. They dont know how do. at that time what to do